# I am not able to scroll to all tag list

Tags: bug, badges, design, profile-page

Please check screenshot. There is no scrollbar outside the popup to scroll down and make the pop up central to the screen. Therefore I am not able to see the badge list.

OS - Windows 10

Browser- chrome 76.0.3809.100

Device - Asus VivoBook S14

[image: Tag]

Comment: If you reduce your browser to a window, how does that look? Maybe your Chrome window is sized to be way bigger than your screen at the moment.

Comment: Reproduced in Chrome on MacOS.  The browser shows a scrollbar for the profile page and that scrollbar disappears when going into the "select badge" dialogue.  Further, the dialogue is not movable like, say, the close dialogue is, so I can't grab it and move it up.

Comment: As a workaround, you can make everything smaller. (Higher resolution. Zoom Out (80-90%)). But that seems fairly problematic, especially if you have difficulty seeing anything smaller than what you have right now.

Answer (score 3):

I see the problem.  It does not change placement depending on the size of the browser window.  It places the top of the popup at a particular distance from the top of of the window, regardless of the total height of the window.  I was also able to reproduce it on Chrome on a Mac.

I fixed it with the "command -" shortcut, which is the Mac version of "zoom out" (in the "view" menu).  On Windows machines, use "control -" (the shortcuts are in quotes because that hyphen/minus key is in fact the key you use and not the usual separator to tell you to push both keys at once).

Be sure that you use the above command or another that is meant to change the size on the current page.  There are other commands for changing them on every page.

[Chrome zoom instructions.](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96810?hl=en)

That said, this is a bug IMHO.  I would check on [Meta StackExchange](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/) and see if it's been asked.  If not, post it.  I did a quick search and don't see this question, but you should also check.  Warning: Meta users can be a bit harsh so don't take it personally if they don't like your question.  Post a link here so we can all go weigh in.

Comment: Sure will check this out if it is already posted on meta or not.